# Adding another directory to the env:temp

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to use

```
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $env:temp/newfolder
```

Obviously this won't work because `$env:temp` doesn't allow for the `/newfolder`.  I am trying to use this to access a folder I create earlier in the script.  The full functionality of the script is to extract from a zip to a temp folder, I don't want to use hard coded paths so I am trying to extract it to a folder in the user temp folder.

What is the easiest way to create a variable using `env:temp` with an added directory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to create the directory? It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: I can create the directory but I need to use hardcoded paths.  I am trying to avoid using a hard coded path like C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Local\Temp, I would prefer to use something that is based on the gci cmdlet.  If I could use the env:temp and have a variable to pass that plus a folder I create that would be what I need.  For example, $deploylocation= $env:temp/newfolder.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I think so. You are just trying to build a variable using $env:temp. Try this: `$deploylocation = ($env:temp) + '\newfolder\'`

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. I set an answer if you want to mark it.

Comment: `$deploylocation= $env:temp/newfolder` doesnt work since PowerShell will attempt to divide `$env:temp/newfolder` much like `1/2` would yeild `0.5`. Putting `"$env:temp\newfolder"` in quotes and using a proper slash should also have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand the variable first to build the full string. Do it like this.

```
$deploylocation = ($env:temp) + '\newfolder\'
```

Comment: `$deploylocation= "$env:temp\newfolder"` would have worked as well.

Answer (score 3):

Another option

```
 $deploylocation = Join-path $env:temp newfolder
```